# How to avoid nested for loops in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, nested-loops

I have this code.

```
n_nodes = len(data_x)
X = np.zeros((n_nodes, n_nodes))

for i in range(n_nodes):
  for j in range(n_nodes):
    X[i, j] = data_x[i] ** j
```

I want to do the same task with no loops used at all. How can I do that with NumPy functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest

```
data_x[:,None]**np.arange(n_nodes)
```

A check

```
In [17]: data_x = np.array((3,5,7,4,6))
    ...: n_nodes = len(data_x)
    ...: X = np.zeros((n_nodes, n_nodes))
    ...: 
    ...: for i in range(n_nodes):
    ...:   for j in range(n_nodes):
    ...:     X[i, j] = data_x[i] ** j
    ...: print(X)
    ...: print('-----------')
    ...: print(data_x[:,None]**np.arange(n_nodes))
[[1.000e+00 3.000e+00 9.000e+00 2.700e+01 8.100e+01]
 [1.000e+00 5.000e+00 2.500e+01 1.250e+02 6.250e+02]
 [1.000e+00 7.000e+00 4.900e+01 3.430e+02 2.401e+03]
 [1.000e+00 4.000e+00 1.600e+01 6.400e+01 2.560e+02]
 [1.000e+00 6.000e+00 3.600e+01 2.160e+02 1.296e+03]]
-----------
[[   1    3    9   27   81]
 [   1    5   25  125  625]
 [   1    7   49  343 2401]
 [   1    4   16   64  256]
 [   1    6   36  216 1296]]
```

Some timing

```
In [18]: %timeit data_x[:,None]**np.arange(n_nodes)
2.18 µs ± 7.49 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [19]: %%timeit
    ...: for i in range(n_nodes):
    ...:     for j in range(n_nodes):
    ...:         X[i, j] = data_x[i] ** j
10.9 µs ± 107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in one step with [`numpy.power`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html)[`.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html):

```
np.power.outer(data_x, np.arange(len(data_x)))
```

Comment: nice solution. Is this documented somewhere? I am asking, because it is not mentionen in the `numpy.power` manual page.

Comment: @user_na Yes, I split the link in two parts. This is `numpy.ufunc.outer` ;)

Comment: `np.power` is a `ufunc` that takes 2 arguments.  This category of functions has methods like `outer`.  However, it's usually just as easy to use `broadcasting` as done in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If `data_x` is big, you will be faster using only numpy functions.
You can first repeat the input array and then use `np.power` with a vector giving the powers. This should be calculated fully vectorised in comparison to the already given list comprehension version.

```
x = np.arange(10)
X = x[:,np.newaxis].repeat(x.size,axis=1)
X = np.power(X,np.arange(x.size))
```

If `data_x` is already a numpy array, you can use it directly, if not you would need to do

```
x = np.array(data_x)
```

Comment: Under the rules of `broadcasting` you don't need to use `repeat`.  Simply make `x` a (10,1) array.